# How to Stop a Button Animating by conditions

Tags: swift, animation, uibutton, removeall

I have a function which animates a certain button into fading in and fading out. I initiate the animate in `viewDidLoad`, so the animation is working once I open the app. The button takes me to an input window, and when the input fields have input, I want the animation to stop. Ive tried removing the animation from the text with conditions, but the animation keeps animating, even when the conditions are meet.
How could I create a function that removes this animation?

Heres my code:

```
func animateText(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.EnterDet.alpha = 1
    }, completion:  {
        (Comnpleted : Bool) -> Void in

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.EnterDet.alpha = 0.1

        }, completion: {
            (Completed : Bool) -> Void in
            self.animateText()
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting this to false? .setAnimationsEnabled(enabled: Bool)

Comment: Thats not working. I think the problem is that the animation is repeating? Im new to swift, so I have no idea where to start in creating a function that stops this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the completion blocks to check the `completed` parameter.  `completed` is `true` when the animation completes (that is, when it wasn't cancelled).  Only when `completed` is `true` do you want to invoke the next step of the animation.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.EnterDet.alpha = 1
}, completion:  {

(completed : Bool) -> Void in
    if completed {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.EnterDet.alpha = 0.1

        }, completion: {
            (completed : Bool) -> Void in
            if completed {
                self.animateText()
            } else {
                self.EnterDet.alpha = 1
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Then, when you want to end the animation, call:

```
self.EnterDet.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: Still didn't work? Ive put the condition as         `if Voutput.text != ""{
        self.EnterDet.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        } else {
        animateText()        }` and the animation still wont turn off?

Comment: Where are you putting that code?  Did you add *both* `if completed` blocks?

Comment: *the button takes me to an input window*.  Is that with a *segue*?

Comment: The input window is a pop up in the same view controller

Comment: Are you sure `viewDidAppear` is called when you think it is being called?

Comment: When should I be calling `ViewDidAppear`?